# Python: "self" in inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

A basic question on inheritance and "self" here.

**Good code** with no error: 
(***Correction***: Turns out this is NOT GOOD, either. Please refer to MisterMiyagi's answers below.)

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = 10
    self.b = { 'a': 10, 'b': 20 }
    self.c = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(self)
    print(self.a)
    print(self.b)
    print(self.c)

i = B()
```

**Bad code** with errors:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.a = 10
    self.b = { 'a': 10, 'b': 20 }
    self.c = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(self)
    print(self.a)
    print(self.b)
    print(self.c)

i = B()
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./o", line 16, in <module>
    i = B()
  File "./o", line 11, in __init__
    super().__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'c'
```

Could you please explain why it has to be:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a):
```

but neither

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
```

nor

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a, b, c):
```

?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that ``super().__init__(self)`` is not correct, unless the intention is to bind ``a=self``. ``super().__init__()`` should be used, and ``A.__init__`` should not take any arguments aside from ``self``.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are not using any of the arguments in the A()'s constructor, so why not either make them optional, or not pass them at all?

Comment: Your `super` call is busted - it should be `super().__init__()`, and `A.__init__` shouldn't take an `a` argument.

Comment: Since ``def __init__(self, a)`` versus ``def __init__(self)`` is a typo/error, can you clarify why you would expect ``def __init__(self, a, b, c)`` to be correct? You are not providing ``b`` or ``c`` anywhere.

Comment: I think MisterMiyagi and Monica gave the direct answer. When I used super().__init__() instead, everything's charm now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a method on `super()` already passes on the first argument (`self` or `cls`) properly. Do not pass along `self` explicitly.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):  # receive implicit self
    self.a = 10
    self.b = { 'a': 10, 'b': 20 }
    self.c = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()  # pass self implicitly
    print(self.a)
    print(self.b)
    print(self.c)

i = B()
```

---

A call such as `super().__init__(self)` passes `self` to the method twice. Thus, the method must take two parameters, e.g. `def __init__(self, a)`. Use just `super().__init__()` and `def __init__(self)` to pass along `self` once instead.

Answer (score 2):

A's constructor takes 3 arguments, and you're giving it 1.  That's the reason for the error.

Since it doesn't use any of the 3 arguments, it should take 0 arguments, and B in turn should give it 0 arguments:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 10
    self.b = { 'a': 10, 'b': 20 }
    self.c = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print(self.a)
    print(self.b)
    print(self.c)

i = B()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method on an object, the object will be assigned to the `self` argument of the function, for example:

```
class A:
  def someFunc(self):
    pass

a = A()
a.someFunc() # self == a
```

When you are calling the super function, your own class will be assigned to self, you should be calling super like this:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a):
    sef.a = a

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    a = # something
    super(self).__init__(a)
    print(self.a)

i = B()
```

The problem with your code is that you are assigning `a` to `self`, and then not providing a value for `b` and `c`.